# Is there a way to look at the preprocessor expanded file in C

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I want to know how could we look at the **C** file after it has been expanded by the preprocessor before compilation with all the macro values put in the code inside the function where ever they are used.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: a shame we can't add more tags, this could also benefit from being tagged preprocessor related.

Comment: @MattJoiner: Like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can ask gcc to do it for you `gcc -E yourfile.cpp`

That will expand macros and include files, all the preproccessing.

Answer (score 7):

Just run it through `cpp`:

```
cpp file.c
```

Comment: add `-nostdinc` to the cpp invocation to prevent standard headers from being expanded.

Comment: is there a similar option is gcc also ?